# Python Dataframe extract last reading of the day for many days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe has many timestamps on a given day and many days of the data of the year. I want to extract last reading of the day and store it in a new dataframe.

```
df = 

datetime                     A
01/24/2019 08:27:00 AM    0.905434
01/24/2019 08:28:00 AM    0.913460
01/24/2019 08:29:00 AM    0.926724
01/25/2019 08:30:00 AM    0.937575
01/25/2019 08:31:00 AM    0.946422
01/25/2019 08:32:00 AM    0.951792
01/26/2019 08:33:00 AM    0.957930
01/26/2019 08:34:00 AM    0.963631
01/26/2019 08:35:00 AM    0.968414
01/26/2019 08:36:00 AM    0.972460
```

My code:

```
 aux = []
 for i in df.index.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").unique():
     auxdf = df.loc[i]
     aux.append(auxdf.iloc[-1])
```

It is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby().last()`:

```
df.groupby(df.index.normalize()).last()
```

Output:

```
                   A
datetime            
2019-01-24  0.926724
2019-01-25  0.951792
2019-01-26  0.972460
```

Or `groupby().tail()`:

```
df.groupby(df.index.normalize()).tail(1)
```

Output:

```
                            A
datetime                     
2019-01-24 08:29:00  0.926724
2019-01-25 08:32:00  0.951792
2019-01-26 08:36:00  0.972460
```

Comment: Just make sure the dates are sorted before the `groupby` :)

Comment: Sure! I sort the dates first. I really liked your solution. I was going to through for loops all that stuff. It was not good. Yours just one line. Pretty good. Thanks